# Telegram Bot not making queries (sendMessage, deleteMessage) at same time?

Tags: php, api, bots, telegram-bot

I want to perform these two functionalities at same time i-e sendMessage and Delete the Previous message at the same time by Telegram Bot API.

I don't know why I cant perform these two methods at the same time. only one work.

```
function apiRequestWebhook($method, $parameters) {
$parameters["method"] = $method;
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($parameters);
return true;
}
apiRequestWebhook("deleteMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "message_id" 
=> $message_id));
apiRequestWebhook("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 
"reply_to_message_id" => $message_id, "text" => '中文群组 ： 
https://t.me/SmartMeshCn'));
```

Comment: Can you post what you already tried? Do you get an error? Does the Telegram API return anything?

Comment: Please check out now.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests-when-getting-updates):

> If you're using webhooks, you can perform **a request** to the Bot API while sending an answer to the webhook. Use either application/json or application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data response content type for passing parameters. Specify the method to be invoked in the method parameter of the request. It's not possible to know that such a request was successful or get its result.

Emphasis mine on "a request". In other words, you can't make multiple requests in a same answer - for that, you'll have to call the methods via HTTP yourself, so you'll have to use [curl](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [`file_get_contents`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) (or a [Telegram Bot API library](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core)) to call the methods (as specified in the [Making updates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests) section).

Here it is, for instance, using `file_get_contents`:

```
function apiRequestWebhook($method, $parameters) {
    $parameters["method"] = $method;
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($parameters);
    return true;
}
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:CHANGE_ME/deleteMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&message_id=" . ($message_id-2));
apiRequestWebhook("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 
"reply_to_message_id" => $message_id, "text" => '中文群组 ： 
https://t.me/SmartMeshCn'));
```

Comment: I'm using webhook so can't do 
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:CHANGE_ME/deleteMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&message_id=" . ($message_id-2));

Comment: You can. What you can't do when you have webhooks is making a request to getUpdates. All other requests are possible.

Comment: I dont know why but, this file_get_content method isn't working but apiRequestWebhook do work but just for once :(

Comment: file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot_ID/deleteMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&message_id=".$message_id));

I use this